# Softether VPN with Apache Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, vpn

I have a (azure) server where redmine and Softether VPN is running. Apache httpd distibute the requests to redmine and Softether.

Redmine is working without any problems but I'm not able to use the VPN Server. The connection from the Sothether Client to the server works but I don't get a valid IP Adress from the DHCP.
In the apache logs I get the warning:

```
AH03408: HTTPS: reusable backend connection is not empty: forcibly closed
```

On the Softether log I get this error:

```
On the TCP Listener (Port 443), a Client (IP address ..., Host name "...", Port number 7736) has connected.
For the client (IP address: ..., host name: "...", port number: 7736), connection "CID-32-58873B8941" has been created.
SSL communication for connection "CID-32-58873B8941" has been started. The encryption algorithm name is "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384".
Connection "CID-32-58873B8941" has been terminated.
```

Apache httpd-ssl.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName ...
    
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    
    ProxyPass / https://localhost/ timeout=3600
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost/
    
    SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/cert.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/privkey.pem"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/fullchain.pem"
    
    ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/vpn-error.log"
    TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/vpn-access.log"
    
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    
</VirtualHost>
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with UDP acceleration when the server is behind some local reverse proxy.
Try disable UDP acceleration in the client.